# Cannot run Dropwizard tutorial

Tags: java, dropwizard

I am trying to run the tutorial [here](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/getting-started.html) to get started with Dropwizard.
All things were fine till I run it by this command:

```
java -jar target/hello-world-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar server hello-world.yml
```

As expected it should be

```
INFO  [2011-12-03 00:38:32,927] io.dropwizard.cli.ServerCommand: Starting hello-world
INFO  [2011-12-03 00:38:32,931] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: jetty-7.x.y-SNAPSHOT
INFO  [2011-12-03 00:38:32,936] org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler: started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
INFO  [2011-12-03 00:38:32,999] com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.10 11/02/2011 03:53 PM'
INFO  [2011-12-03 00:38:33,041] io.dropwizard.setup.Environment:

    GET     /hello-world (com.example.helloworld.resources.HelloWorldResource)

INFO  [2011-12-03 00:38:33,215] org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler: started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
INFO  [2011-12-03 00:38:33,235] org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Started BlockingChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080 STARTING
INFO  [2011-12-03 00:38:33,238] org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8081 STARTING
```

but I just got

```
usage: java -jar hello-world-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar [-h] [-v] {server,check} ...

positional arguments:
  {server,check}         available commands

optional arguments:
  -h, --help             show this help message and exit
  -v, --version          show the application version and exit
```

nothing else. It couldn't run!
I'm trying on **Windows 10 64bit, Java 1.8.0_65 and DropWizard 0.9.2**.
Can anyone suggest any clue about this problem? Thanks!

Comment: This app is 100% Java and I just followed exactly what the tutorial described.

Comment: Oh sorry for my missing. Here is the output of `java --help`
Unrecognized option: --help   
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.  
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: Can you please share the content of `hello-world.yml` and is it placed in the same directory form where you are running your `java` command?

Comment: 1. Content of `hello-world.yml` is here: `template: Hello, %s!` 
`defaultName: ${DW_DEFAULT_NAME:-Stranger}`
2. This file is right at the directory I run `java` command

Comment: Your `yml` file does not contain the required configuration settings. OK, your problem is that in the [example documentation](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/getting-started.html#creating-a-configuration-class) they've provided excerpt from the configuration. But if you check you will find a link [to this](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-example/example.yml) also. This are the full contents of the configuration that you need for the example.

Answer (score 0):

Dropwizard takes the first command line argument and dispatches it to a matching command. In this case, the commands available is server and check, which runs your application as an HTTP server. The server command requires a configuration file, you can do it like this :

```
java -jar target/dropwizard-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server hello-world.yml
```

if it is in a subfolder

```
java -jar target/dropwizard-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server conf/hello-world.yml
```

if you do not have config.yml, create one like this template:

[hello-world.yml](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-example/example.yml)